# Classification imagenet - caffe/caffe.hpp: No such a file or directory

Tags: c++, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, imagenet

I trained net using my own dataset via caffe, now I want to write a classification code using C++. My machine (linux) works with CPU only! (I train the net in VM with GPU's).

When I try to "include" specific Caffe header: `#include <caffe/caffe.hpp>` the compiler shows me this message: `fatal error: caffe/caffe.hpp: No such file or directory`.

I tried to copy specific caffe files to `/usr/lib/` but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: ***I tried to copy specific caffe files to /usr/lib/ but it didn't help.*** It should have been /usr/include since the problem is the include files.. Is there a caffe folder in /usr/include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing with Caffe or Deep Learning. You have just missed the right way to include header files.

When you want to include a header file, it should either be in the same folder of the including file or you should write the correct folder. Some IDEs like MSVS (I think all others do too) gives the ability to determine a specific folder where the header file of another library are.

So, just make sure that you have tell the compiler where to find the including folder.

Comment: first of all, thanks for answering. secondly, I know how to "Include files", the problem is running Caffe headers in IDE. it works perfectly on bash (linux shell). if you'll have another idea for solution please share with me. have a good day.

Comment: what's the solution when you run this of Linux terminal using something like `$ g++ -Wall -o ssd_detect ssd_detect.cpp` ?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you just do `#include <caffe.hpp>` and make sure this file is found within one of the include-directories?

Comment: Where does this file reside and whta are your include-directories?

Comment: in Caffe library ( `/home/username/caffe/include/caffe` )

Comment: Does that directory make part of your include-directives (-I)?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. I tried to deliver this directory content to `/usr/lib/` folder and to `#include` this directory as well. but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Within the makefile, you specify in which directories the include-files can be found (the -I<directory> directives). Try adding "-I/home/username/caffe/include/caffe".